# GROUP BY will not work for many with MySQL 5.7 because 5.7 uses the "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" option for SQL_MODE.

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show groups, that should be randomize and showing two group when user open the page. So the following query working fine but GROUP BY not working for many with *MySQL 5.7* uses because *5.7* uses the **"ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"** option for *SQL_MODE*. Apart from `"GROUP BY"`, is there any other query format you can suggest?

**Query must be shown as**

If loged in user id (`$uid`) *IS NOT* joined **group_users**    `F.group_user_id <> '$uid'`

If loged in user id (`$uid`) *IS NOT* group owner (group creator)    **groups** `G.group_owner_id <> '$uid'` .

```
$query = mysqli_query($this->db,"SELECT DISTINCT 
G.group_id, 
G.group_owner_id, 
G.group_name, 
G.group_title, 
G.group_cover, 
F.group_oid, 
F.group_user_id 
FROM groups G, 
group_users F 
WHERE G.status ='1' AND 
G.group_id = F.group_oid AND 
G.group_owner_id <> '$uid' AND 
F.group_user_id <> '$uid' 
GROUP BY G.group_id 
ORDER BY rand() 
LIMIT 2 ") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
```

[image]

Comment: If you read the manual, all you have to do is write your GROUP BY correctly and it will work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need help because I can not do it.

Comment: @Azzo Given that you are using `SELECT DISTINCT`, I speculate that you don't even need to necessarily use `GROUP BY` to get the result you want.  You should be able to just remove it entirely, or include every column in the select statement in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you are using `SELECT DISINCT` already, this implies that you don't even need to use `GROUP BY`.  Just remove it, and the error should go away.  If you wanted to use `GROUP BY` to simulate the effect which `DISTINCT` would have, then you can simply `GROUP BY` every column:

```
SELECT
    G.group_id, 
    G.group_owner_id, 
    G.group_name, 
    G.group_title, 
    G.group_cover, 
    F.group_oid, 
    F.group_user_id 
FROM groups G
INNER JOIN group_users F
    ON G.group_id = F.group_oid
WHERE
    G.status = '1' AND
    G.group_owner_id <> '$uid' AND
    F.group_user_id <> '$uid'
GROUP BY
    G.group_id, 
    G.group_owner_id, 
    G.group_name, 
    G.group_title, 
    G.group_cover, 
    F.group_oid, 
    F.group_user_id
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 2;
```

Note that we would have more work to do if you were also selecting aggregates of some of the columns.  Then, most likely, we would end up introducing one or more subqueries to get around the `GROUP BY` problem you are facing.

Comment: If you `SELECT DISTINCT` a bunch of columns, it is not possible for there to be duplicate rows with regard to those columns.  I'm fairly certain that there is a problem with your data, though I don't know exactly what.  Maybe you can update your question with data from this edge case, and let's try to solve it.

Comment: To put it in the simplest way , `$uid` **4** seeing `group_id` **16**  _two times_. because `$uid` **4** is not joined `group_oid` **16** from in `group_users` table

Comment: @Azzo This isn't strictly a duplicate of two records then, it is only a duplicate of the `group_id` value.  Then, you would need to provide logic for choosing one of those two records.  Really, it would be better if you could provide a minimal question with sample data, and the output you want.